# $n \times n$ matrices $A$ and $J$ satisfy $A + A^T = (1/n)J, AJ = (1/2)J$ where $J$ is the matrix all of whose entries are 1

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For a positive integer $n$, assume that $n \times n$ matrices $A$ and $J$ satisfy
$$A + A^T = (1/n)J$$
$$AJ = (1/2)J$$
where $J$ is the matrix all of whose entries are $1$.
it it true for that $(A^m - I)$ is invertible for positive odd integer $m$??

Comment: A matrix $A$ with $A+A^t=JAJ/n=J/2$ may not exist for given $n$. For example, it does not exist for $n=3$.

Comment: Are you familiar with the `\frac{}{}` command?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: use Cauchy-Schwarz (or the spectrum of $J$) to show that any vector $x$ satisfies $x^*(A^*+A)x\leq x^*x$ where the superscript $*$ means Hermitian transpose, and deduce that any eigenvalue has real part at most $1/2.$ The second equation is not needed.